# How to find URLs that starts with "/" and contain "php"?

Tags: regex, xml, atom-editor, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have a 95MB XML file of content that is going from an old CMS (Drupal via Wordpress) to a new CMS (Squarespace).

The Squarespace import process keeps breaking & it appears to come down to links that attempt to execute PHP in the new server.

For example:
`<img src="/generate-image.php">`

During the import process the new CMS recognises this as an internal link & tries to execute that URL to import the content, treats it as an attack or attempt at code injection & shuts down the process.

So I want a way of finding URLs that start with "/" & contain "php" so I can remove them.

I should be clear I only want to identify internal links & not external links to other sites.

Is this possible via Regex? I'd really like to avoid writing script to do this if I can just plug a Regex statement into Atom & Find/Replace.

Comment: Try with use of negated class, eg: [`\/[^\s"'><]+\.php`](https://regex101.com/r/Euh26F/1)

Comment: @bobblebubble - `"\/[^\s"'><]+\.php` works. I needed to add the `"` at the beginning so it only found local URLs. If you'd like to make this an answer I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about some simple regex by use of a [negated class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
"\/[^\s"'><]+\.php
```

- `[^\s"'><]` matches any character besides *white space*, quotes, greater/lesser sign
- add [word boundary `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) after `php` if desired

[Here is the demo at regex101 comparing internal php links to external php links](https://regex101.com/r/Euh26F/2)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible whith Regex. Try with this one:

```
(\/*)[\w.]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+\b.php\b
```

It will be match all possible charakters for valid URL.

Comment: Almost! This produces false positives like a url starting with `http://`. I've tried to change it so the first two characters have to be `"/` but my regex-fu is nowhere near as good as yours.

Comment: Ok Try so:    (\/\/)[\w.]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+\b.php\b